# Window Scroll listener for multiple divs at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I'd like to build an indicator in a fixed nav bar that shows a user which section of a page they are on, and changes appropriately as they scroll, essentially recreating [this Bootstrap effect](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<li class='page-nav' data-dest='thing1'><a>Event Info</a></li>
<li class='page-nav' data-dest='thing2'><a>Venue</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
var sections = []; 
$('.page-nav').each(function() {
    var destination = $(this).data('dest');
    sections.push('#'+destination);
})
```

This gives me an array like this:

```
["#thing1", "#thing2"]
```

How could I then write a window.scroll function to watch if any of the DOM elements from the array enter scrollspy? Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ($(any-of-the-sections).on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
        $(whichever-section-entered).addClass('active');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li class='page-nav' data-dest='thing1'><a href="#">Event Info</a></li>
      <li class='page-nav' data-dest='thing2'><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
    </ul>

    <hr>

    <div id="thing1">
      <p>Sed suscipit libero eros, ut dictum orci ullamcorper eu. Suspendisse hendrerit arcu felis, eget fermentum erat vulputate vitae. In sagittis sapien sed ex maximus commodo. Maecenas ultrices, ex eu commodo iaculis, massa tortor posuere lorem, sit amet sodales purus odio pellentesque nunc. Donec tellus enim, finibus id tincidunt et, vestibulum a justo. Morbi venenatis sapien sit amet interdum dictum. Vivamus et diam justo. Nunc ultrices placerat nibh, in convallis justo efficitur a. Morbi ut pharetra urna. Vestibulum id nulla id tellus fringilla mollis in non lorem. Ut vitae diam accumsan, finibus velit eget, cursus orci. Ut sem enim, mollis ut ullamcorper quis, scelerisque vitae ex.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut enim molestie, ullamcorper eros in, vehicula enim. Proin id blandit turpis, sed varius dui. Suspendisse sodales nec nisi interdum aliquam. Cras auctor orci orci. Mauris sit amet iaculis leo, eget aliquam turpis. Proin ac dapibus mi. Nullam arcu risus, elementum ut felis et, pellentesque aliquet felis. Proin interdum luctus aliquet.</p>
      <p>Curabitur laoreet, mi scelerisque pharetra consequat, ex urna volutpat ligula, eu sodales nisi felis nec tellus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus libero neque, dictum in metus vel, lobortis sodales odio. Nullam vestibulum at dolor et semper. Sed ac nibh malesuada, consectetur est ut, gravida dolor. Etiam rhoncus ultricies arcu sed pretium. Curabitur accumsan vel erat ac porttitor.</p>
      <p>Proin nec lorem magna. Nullam lectus ex, rhoncus non libero ornare, placerat pharetra turpis. Sed commodo dui ut dictum ullamcorper. Nunc dui mi, iaculis non elit ac, pretium mattis nunc. Curabitur interdum dignissim quam, quis vulputate lectus. Sed enim massa, faucibus quis ante ac, eleifend scelerisque velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam blandit accumsan rhoncus. Donec sagittis egestas tellus, non scelerisque dolor commodo porta. Ut vehicula suscipit orci vel bibendum. Nulla facilisi. Cras sit amet molestie urna, quis blandit metus. Sed a arcu massa. Integer varius finibus neque in venenatis.</p>
      <p>Sed suscipit libero eros, ut dictum orci ullamcorper eu. Suspendisse hendrerit arcu felis, eget fermentum erat vulputate vitae. In sagittis sapien sed ex maximus commodo. Maecenas ultrices, ex eu commodo iaculis, massa tortor posuere lorem, sit amet sodales purus odio pellentesque nunc. Donec tellus enim, finibus id tincidunt et, vestibulum a justo. Morbi venenatis sapien sit amet interdum dictum. Vivamus et diam justo. Nunc ultrices placerat nibh, in convallis justo efficitur a. Morbi ut pharetra urna. Vestibulum id nulla id tellus fringilla mollis in non lorem. Ut vitae diam accumsan, finibus velit eget, cursus orci. Ut sem enim, mollis ut ullamcorper quis, scelerisque vitae ex.</p>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id="thing2">
      <p>Mauris in lacus metus. Sed vitae aliquet ligula. Sed eget arcu ornare lacus efficitur interdum quis at dui. Cras rhoncus, odio eget ultricies sollicitudin, sem sapien scelerisque leo, sit amet auctor nibh risus at erat. Sed vitae metus pretium neque porttitor sollicitudin pellentesque laoreet lacus. Donec luctus tellus et maximus venenatis. Nulla eget aliquet nulla, aliquet cursus purus. In viverra erat a pharetra egestas. In id faucibus velit, et sagittis ex. Aliquam ut semper nunc. Sed id tempus nisl. Nunc tincidunt porta velit, sit amet sagittis velit porttitor ut. Cras feugiat pulvinar augue in consectetur. Praesent quis nisl purus. Suspendisse aliquet metus eros, a aliquet risus viverra consectetur. Aliquam a nulla sit amet erat iaculis facilisis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut enim molestie, ullamcorper eros in, vehicula enim. Proin id blandit turpis, sed varius dui. Suspendisse sodales nec nisi interdum aliquam. Cras auctor orci orci. Mauris sit amet iaculis leo, eget aliquam turpis. Proin ac dapibus mi. Nullam arcu risus, elementum ut felis et, pellentesque aliquet felis. Proin interdum luctus aliquet.</p>
      <p>Curabitur laoreet, mi scelerisque pharetra consequat, ex urna volutpat ligula, eu sodales nisi felis nec tellus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus libero neque, dictum in metus vel, lobortis sodales odio. Nullam vestibulum at dolor et semper. Sed ac nibh malesuada, consectetur est ut, gravida dolor. Etiam rhoncus ultricies arcu sed pretium. Curabitur accumsan vel erat ac porttitor.</p>
      <p>Proin nec lorem magna. Nullam lectus ex, rhoncus non libero ornare, placerat pharetra turpis. Sed commodo dui ut dictum ullamcorper. Nunc dui mi, iaculis non elit ac, pretium mattis nunc. Curabitur interdum dignissim quam, quis vulputate lectus. Sed enim massa, faucibus quis ante ac, eleifend scelerisque velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam blandit accumsan rhoncus. Donec sagittis egestas tellus, non scelerisque dolor commodo porta. Ut vehicula suscipit orci vel bibendum. Nulla facilisi. Cras sit amet molestie urna, quis blandit metus. Sed a arcu massa. Integer varius finibus neque in venenatis.</p>
      <p>Sed suscipit libero eros, ut dictum orci ullamcorper eu. Suspendisse hendrerit arcu felis, eget fermentum erat vulputate vitae. In sagittis sapien sed ex maximus commodo. Maecenas ultrices, ex eu commodo iaculis, massa tortor posuere lorem, sit amet sodales purus odio pellentesque nunc. Donec tellus enim, finibus id tincidunt et, vestibulum a justo. Morbi venenatis sapien sit amet interdum dictum. Vivamus et diam justo. Nunc ultrices placerat nibh, in convallis justo efficitur a. Morbi ut pharetra urna. Vestibulum id nulla id tellus fringilla mollis in non lorem. Ut vitae diam accumsan, finibus velit eget, cursus orci. Ut sem enim, mollis ut ullamcorper quis, scelerisque vitae ex.</p>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script>
      var sections = [];

      $('.page-nav').each(function() {
        var destination = $(this).data('dest');
        sections.push('#'+destination);
      });

      $.each(sections, function(index, value) {
        var section = $(sections[index]);

        $(section).scrollSpy();

        $(section).on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        $(section).on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, it's possible for more than one section to be active at any given time. Just because `#thing2` has become visible doesn't mean that `#thing1` has necessarily scrolled outside of the viewport yet.

If you want to ensure that only one section has the `active` class at any given time, then you can delete the `scrollSpy:exit` event handler and modify the `scrollSpy:enter` event handler to look like this:

```
$(section).on('scrollSpy:enter', function() {
  $.each(sections, function(index, value) {
    $(sections[index]).removeClass('active');
  });
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

In this modified version of the code, when a section scrolls into view, we remove the `active` class from every section before adding it to the one that has scrolled into view.